# Flex items aren't centering within container?

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I'm attempting to center the flex items, however I must be doing something wrong because it isn't working. The basic outline is that `Timeline-Container` holds 3 smaller containers (`TL-1`,`TL-2`, etc). Everything is working fine between the parent container and the children container (meaning that all the `TL-#` containers are centered correctly with flex), however none of the items within the `TL-#` containers are centering.

I've tried "justify-content: center;" and it isn't affecting anything.

```
<div id="Timeline-Container">
        <div id="TL-1">
            <img src="Photos/2018 SB Photos/Lighted_Stadium_1.JPG">
            <p>Caption 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="TL-2">
            <img src="Photos/2018 SB Photos/Lighted_Stadium_2.JPG">
            <p>Caption 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="TL-3">
            <img src="Photos/2018 SB Photos/Lighted_Stadium_3.JPG">
            <p>Caption 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
#Timeline-Container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#Timeline-Container img {
    height: 35%;
    width: 35%;
    border: 5px solid #cccccc;
}

#TL-1 {
    /*Parent Flex Code*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items; center;
    /*Child Flex Code*/
    order: 1;
}

#TL-2 {
    /*Parent Flex Code*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items; center;
    /*Child Flex Code*/
    order: 2;
}

#TL-3 {
    /*Parent Flex Code*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items; center;
    /*Child Flex Code*/
    order: 3;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `align-items; center;` which has a semi-colon instead of `align-items: center;` which has a colon. Here is a code pen: https://codepen.io/the_legitTDM/pen/NQXPWv
FYI: There is added margin for better viewing

Answer (score 1):

The `justify-content` rule only works on actual flex items. Flex items are elements whose immediate parent has `display: flex;` set. So if you want to center the content in your `#TL-?` items usinf flexbox rules, you will need to add `display: flex` to them as well.

My favorite flexbox resource, helps the concepts just make sense: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Right, however each of the `TL` (which contains the items) has display set to flex, but it's still not centering them.